# ORDER BY "the date" Laravel 5 SQL Query

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to sort the results by the date, but this Laravel 5 SQL Query is not working as i want.

```
$b = DB::table('entry')
                        ->select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y') as tanggal"))
                        ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y')"))
                        ->orderBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y')"), 'asc')
                        ->get();
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')`

Comment: Could you post your desired results and your actual results please? Until then, we are guessing what you actually hope to achieve. I am not sure why are combining a groupBy and orderBy. Also, could the DATE_FORMAT in your orderBy be interfering with your results? As Uchiha already mentions, just try `->orderBy('created_at','asc')`

Answer (score 33):

Here's the easy way to achieve this

**Step 1 :**

Create a Model named as `Entry` by artisan command or manually

**Step 2 :**

Then from your Controller just do

```
$entry = Entry::orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')->get();
```

Then you should get the `$entry` array of what you need.

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can still use DB::table and simply put this orderBy. It will work just like the above mentioned.

```
$query = DB::table('entry')
           ->select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y') as tanggal"))
           ->orderBy('created_at','ASC')->get(); //either this
           ->orderBy('updated_at','ASC')->get(); // or this

$query = DB::table('entry')
           ->select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y') as tanggal"))
           ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get(); //either this
           ->orderBy('updated_at','DESC')->get(); // or this
```

**Note**: Either you put ***'ASC'*** or not it will automatically sort it ascendingly.